# can't call a function for a class member

Tags: c++, class, methods, runtime-error

In the following example, why I can't call car.getFuelConsumption

```
class Road {
public:
    double length(); // km
    int speed(); // km per hour ;
};

class Car {
protected:
    virtual double getFuelConsumption(int speed_in_km) = 0;
};

class Tank: public Car{
public:
    double getFuelConsumption(int speed_in_km) {
        return 1;
    }
};

double getPetrol(std::vector<Road> roads, const Car &car) {
    double total_fuel_consumption=0;
    for (int i=0;i<roads.size();++i)
    {
        double fuel_consumption_per_road = car.getFuelConsumption(roads[i].speed());
    }
    return total_fuel_consumption;
}
```

Every car has such a method so why I can't call it? For Example if I send a Tank to `getPetrol()` then I expect it to work and call Tank's version of `getFuelConsumption()`

---

> ```
> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "Road::speed()", referenced from:
> getPetrol(std::__1::vector<Road, std::__1::allocator<Road> >, Car const&) 
> in main.cpp.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture
> x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> ```

Comment: `car.getFuelConsumption` isn't how one call a function. Doing e.g. `total_fuel_consumption += car.getFuelConsumption(some_speed_value);` is how you call the function and use its returned value.

Comment: Try to read about dynamic v/s static binding.

Comment: I know but I just wanted to give simple example

Comment: If you get build errors, you should really include both a [mcve] which results in the errors, as well as the actual errors themselves (copy-pasted as text, in full and complete), with comments on the lines where you get errors. Please also take some time to read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: That error says that the `Road::speed` function doesn't exist (it's not *defined*, i.e. it's not implemented). Is it implemented in some other source file that you forgot to include in your project or forgot to build with?

Answer (score 1):

The visible issues with your code are the following:

- `getPetrol()` is defined outside the class and it calls a protected member `getFuelConsumption()`, protected members can't be called outside the class.

  To fix it you make `getFuelConsumption()` a `public` method in the base class.
- Because you have a `const` object argument `const Car &car`, the method `getFuelConsumption()` needs to have `const` return, `const` objects can't call non-const methods. You could also remove `const` keyword from the `car` argument, but the first option is adequate in this case.
- As you are going to use references of the abstract base class to derived classes, effectively polymorphism, the use of a virtual destructor is also advised, under penalty of invoking undefined behavior.
- The linker error you mention can be because `Road` methods are declared but not defined, at least not in the code you show.

Corrected code:

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4ANqU2bGFH9AhZ52)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Road {
public:
    double length(){ return 0;} // added function body to avoid linker error
    int speed(){ return 0; }    // ""  
};

class Car {
public:
    virtual double getFuelConsumption(int speed_in_km) const = 0;
    virtual ~Car(){} //virtual destructor
};

class Tank : public Car {
public:
    double getFuelConsumption(int speed_in_km) const {
        return speed_in_km;
    }
};

double getPetrol(std::vector<Road> roads, const Car &car) {
    double total_fuel_consumption = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < roads.size(); ++i) {
        total_fuel_consumption += car.getFuelConsumption(roads[i].speed());
    }
    return total_fuel_consumption;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

car is `const`, but the method is not `const`. You cannot call a non-const method on a const object. See https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/810-const-class-objects-and-member-functions/

Comment: If I write: "double fuel_consumption_per_road = car.getFuelConsumption(roads[i].speed());" I get linker error

Comment: Thats possible, depends on what you link. Road for example is not part of your source code...

Comment: Any help with this?

Comment: I believe it is the answer to the question why he cannot call the method. You cannot call a non-const method on a const object. The question was edited and a second part was added.